# Partial least squares (PLS)

Tags: linear-regression, orange, partial-least-squares

I am relatively new to Orange, trying to utilise it for linear regression, in particular [partial least squares (PLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_least_squares_regression). My statistics knowledge is in the moment not good enough to know whether I could compose an equivalent by combinding PCA with ordinary linear regression, but I would anyhow have expected a dedicated PLS widget - or as an option in the Linear regression widget.

I even found a description of PLS functionality in Orange2 [here](https://docs.biolab.si//2/reference/rst/Orange.regression.pls.html), but this is not available (or moved to where I don't find it) in Orange3.

Well, I have a python/numpy PLS implementation that I could probably adapt into a python script block, but is this necessary? Please tell me that it's just a mouse-click/import away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Well, I have a python/numpy PLS implementation that I could probably
>   adapt into a python script block, but is this necessary? Please tell
>   me that it's just a mouse-click/import away.

Welcome to the site! I wish I could tell you that what you want is a simple point-and-click but I don't think that it will be.

Generally speaking, most people use Orange as a tool for the visualization layer while you are looking for a tool for your modeling layer. Python has tons and tons of tools that you can use for modeling and should fit what you need. So, while that will be more steps for you, it will ultimately provide you more flexibility for other projects you may do in the future; just use Orange for the visualizations.

Comment: Thanks. That is also good to know and saves me further seeking. Still, of course, I am slightly confused why it was included in the python API of Orange2 - and not in V3.